# How to find possible unquoted pattern after predicate `-exec'?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

I have 5 files that I want to unrar(and I have done it many times):

```
find . -name "*.rar"
./Udemy_Kubernetes_Mastery_Hands-On_Lessons_From_A_Docker_Captain_2020-4.part5_Downloadly.ir.rar
./Udemy_Kubernetes_Mastery_Hands-On_Lessons_From_A_Docker_Captain_2020-4.part2_Downloadly.ir.rar
./Udemy_Kubernetes_Mastery_Hands-On_Lessons_From_A_Docker_Captain_2020-4.part4_Downloadly.ir.rar
./Udemy_Kubernetes_Mastery_Hands-On_Lessons_From_A_Docker_Captain_2020-4.part1_Downloadly.ir.rar
./Udemy_Kubernetes_Mastery_Hands-On_Lessons_From_A_Docker_Captain_2020-4.part3_Downloadly.ir.rar
```

My command

```
find . -name "*.rar" -exec unrar x -o+ \; Udemy_Kubernetes_Mastery_Hands-On_Lessons_From_A_Docker_Captain_2020-4.part1_Downloadly.ir.rar
```

I got error

```
find: paths must precede expression: `Udemy_Kubernetes_Mastery_Hands-On_Lessons_From_A_Docker_Captain_2020-4.part1_Downloadly.ir.rar'
find: possible unquoted pattern after predicate `-exec'?
```

Why?

Comment: You are exiting the `-exec` before adding the filename to unrar. You can use `{}` for accessing the results filename/path

Comment: @mashuptwice Yes,I get it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your command into:

```sh
find . -name "*.rar" -exec unrar x -o+ {} \;
```

Where `{}` represents the file found by the `find` command.